# What does [urlString componentsSeperatedByString: @"?"] [0]? mean in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm not entirely sure what

```
NSString * fileName = [self cachedFileNameForKey:[urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"][0]];
```

Means from this code.  I am primely writing in Swift so this notation is a bit confusing for me.  What does the double [ ] notation mean? 3d array?

```
+ (AVPlayerItem *)localDownloadedVideoFromUrl:(NSURL *)url {
      NSString * urlString = url.absoluteString;
      NSString * fileName = [self cachedFileNameForKey:[urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"][0]];
      TWRDownloadManager * manager = [TWRDownloadManager sharedManager];
      if ([manager fileExistsWithName:fileName]) {
           AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[manager localPathForFile:fileName]]];
           return item;
      }
      return [NSNull null];
   }
```

Comment: It looks like [0] is picking object from 0th index.

Comment: Note that you should get the file name from suggestedFilename property of the URLResponse from the server

Answer (score 2):

`[]` in objective-c is not only used to access arrays, but also used to call methods. Surprising, isn't it?

In general,

```
[xxx someMethod];
```

is equivalent to:

```
xxx.someMethod()
```

in swift.

So here:

```
[urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"][0]
```

means

```
urlString.components(separatedBy: "?")[0] // "[0]" can also be replaced by ".first", which is safer.
```

This is then passed to the `cachedFileNameForKey` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift

```
var urlString: String = "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this" // Example string or url.absoluteString

let fileName = urlString.components(separatedBy: "?")
print(fileName)

let string1 = fileName[0]
let string2 = fileName[1]
```

Hope will helpful to you

Answer (score -1):

Ahh so mistake on my part is that I didn't see what the method `-cacheFileNameForKey:` was doing.

```
+ (nullable NSString *)cachedFileNameForKey:(nullable NSString *)key {
     const char *str = key.UTF8String;
     if (str == NULL) {
        str = "";
     }
       unsigned char r[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
       CC_MD5(str, (CC_LONG)strlen(str), r);
       NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%@",
                      r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10],
                      r[11], r[12], r[13], r[14], r[15], [key.pathExtension isEqualToString:@""] ? @"" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", key.pathExtension]];

       return filename;
 }
```

I guess its used for a function to generate a file name for a temporary movie file.